# efficient mySQL fulltext index

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-indexing

I'm looking to store the results of a game in a table. Each round will be played by 2-10 players. Each player will score between 1-5 points. I need an efficient way to retrieve all rounds for a given player/score range. For example:

```
select all rounds where Hamburger14 scored 5
select all rounds where Cheese3 scored 1
select all rounds where Hotdog99 scored 4
```

My first thought was to use a fulltext indexed varchar field "player_score" and populate it like so:

```
player1:0-player2:3-player3.1
```

Then if I want all rounds where player1 scored 5 I would do:

```
select * from rounds where match(player_score) against("player1.5")
```

If the player pool stays small and the scores are only ever 1-5 this seems like it'd work although I might need to mess with the default mySQL stoplist or use HEX values for the score etc.

But something about this seems *very* ugly. Any suggestions?

Optional: If in the future if I want to retrieve rounds given a player and SCORE RANGE (for example, all rounds where playerX scored 3 OR MORE), how might this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

FULLTEXT -- no.

```
CREATE TABLE Rounds (
    round_num SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    player VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
    score TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(round_num, player),
    INDEX(player, score)
);
```

Then do

```
SELECT * FROM Rounds
     WHERE player = "player1"
       AND score = 5;
```

To get the rest of the info about the round(s):

```
SELECT r.*
     FROM ( SELECT round_num FROM Rounds
               WHERE player = "player1"
                 AND score = 5 ) AS x
     JOIN Rounds AS r USING(round_num);
```

Comment: Along with the participants and scores I also want to save the full round transcript (will require many fields) - you're saying this should go in another table entirely? I avoided this approach originally because of redundancy and the need for large joins.

Comment: @ReallyMadeMeThink - I added a query that may get what you want.

Comment: That'd work. It just doesn't seem elegant since the entire "rounds" table is redundant and essentially only functions as an index. I hoped there was a simple way to index "the existence of x in a set of no more than 10" but it doesn't look promising.

Comment: @ReallyMadeMeThink - I think I need to see a sample dataset to understand your "not elegant" criticism.

Comment: Consider storing complete poker hands. Each hand has participants but also starting stacks, seat positions, betting action, flop, turn, river, showdown, and who won. If I want to query a particular player's tendencies in certain spots I'll first want to narrow my search to hands which were played by that player, which is why I'm looking to index this property but afterwards I may very well narrow my search further on other fields...

Comment: I can do as suggested and maintain another table mapping players to hand id's but this table is 100% redundant and is functioning only as an index. Preferably there will be only 1 table with the ability to index certain rows based on the existence of a certain player.